# React: Reset Text Input from another Component

Tags: reactjs

How do I reset the Textfield in my `<Search/>` Component when I click the Logo in my `<Header />` Component?

The `<Search/>` Component is already entangled with another Component through Callbacks and props.
I've tried custom Events, creating a higher Level State and passing the Event up through a Callback and then down again through a prop. This led to glitches and infinite rerenders or Invalid Hook Calls.

Whats the proper and best way to Pass this "Clear Event" to the `<Search/>` Component without running into those issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Context API](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) is how you get shared variables / functions between components.

You can put the value of the search bar into a context to allow other components to modify it.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jxsehh?file=src%2Findex.tsx

Snippet:

```js
const SearchCtx = React.createContext(null);

const SearchCtxProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const searchTextState = React.useState('');
  return (
    <SearchCtx.Provider value={searchTextState}>{children}</SearchCtx.Provider>
  );
};

function Header() {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useContext(SearchCtx);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setSearchText('')}>RESET</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Search() {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useContext(SearchCtx);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Search</h2>
      <input
        value={searchText}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <SearchCtxProvider>
      <Header />
      <Search />
    </SearchCtxProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This works, thank you! However I'm reusing the Header Comp in other Pages, there the Click should also Navigate to the Main Page. I was using `Navigate("/")`, but calling this in the `onClick` Handler gives me an "Invalid Hook Call Error". How do I implement the navigation feature?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [useContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) for handling the state of a small app.

Here's a working example

```js
const AppContext = React.createContext({
  search: "",
  setSearch: () => { console.error("setSearch called outside of app context") }
})

function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("")
  const appContext = {search, setSearch}
  return <AppContext.Provider value={appContext}>
    <Logo />
    <Search />
  </AppContext.Provider>
}

function Logo() {
  const { setSearch } = React.useContext(AppContext)
  return <a href="#" onClick={() => setSearch("")}></a>
}

function Search() {
  const { search, setSearch } = React.useContext(AppContext)
  return <input value={search} onChange={e => setSearch(e.currentTarget.value)} placeholder="search..." />
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```